# HiTechnic Colour Sensor unable to detect black colour on EV3 brick

Tags: nxt, lego-mindstorms

I am using HiTechnic Colour Sensor for Lego Mindstorms NXT. I am using the Lego Mindstorms EV3 Software Version 1.2.1, EV3 Brick and Firmware Version 1.09H. I have two new HiTechnic Colour Sensors (which I am using for the first time). The issue is that both of them are not detecting black colours. They are correctly detecting all other colours (red, blue...) and I am confused and unable to diagnose the problem as to why it is unable to detect black colour. Is there any configuration required?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to place the sensor in an angle (there is a recommended angle and distance). Earlier I was not placing it at angle. The sensor works best when it is placed at a certain angle.